# a function that supposed to return a different value each time does not work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on my portfolio, but when I reach the experiences page I tried to create a title that has it's middle part change every second, and value of it must come from an already set up array,
but when I run the code it always return the first string of the array,
can anyone please fix this problem for me ?

```
const projectsTitleKeyWords = ['responsible', 'meaningful', 'beautiful']
let titlep2 = 'test'
let index = 0

const change = () => { 
  titlep2 = projectsTitleKeyWords[index]
  index = ++index % projectsTitleKeyWords.length
  setTimeout(change, 1000)
}
change()
console.log(titlep2)


const titlep1 = 'I creat '
const titlep1Array = titlep1.split('')
let titlep2Array = titlep2.split('')
const titlep3 = ' projects'
const titlep3Array = titlep3.split('')
```

the value of titlep2Array will be received by

```
<AnimatedLetters
   letterClass={letterClass}
   strArray={titlep2Array}
   idx={15}
   id='to-change'
/>
```

Comment: Given `titlep2Array` changes each time (new array), `AnimatedLetters` should be rerendered. Can you share some context of where all of this code is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In-order to reflect UI changes in React, a component must re-render.**

A React component re-renders in 1 of 2 scenarios:

1. Whenever there's a change in the value of a local state.
2. Whenever any of it's parent components re-render.

Therefor, since changes in the UI are only reflected upon a re-render, we should manage a local state that would be responsible for this behavior.
With functional components in React, this can be achieved via the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.

In your case, we can simply make `titlep2` a state, instead of a regular variable.

**Example:**

```
const [titlep2, setTitlep2] = useState('')

const change = () => { 
  setTitlep2(projectsTitleKeyWords[index])
  index = ++index % projectsTitleKeyWords.length
  setTimeout(change, 1000)
}

<AnimatedLetters
   letterClass={letterClass}
   strArray={titlep2.split('')}
   idx={15}
   id='to-change'
/>
```

**Note:** since this function now updates the state, we can't call it the way you did in your example, since it will run every time the component re-renders, making the component re-render indefinitely due to the change in state.

Therefor, we can use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook in-order to allow it to run only once on the initial render.

**Example:**

```
const change = () => { 
  setTitlep2(projectsTitleKeyWords[index])
  index = ++index % projectsTitleKeyWords.length
  setTimeout(change, 1000)
}

useEffect(() => {
   change()
}, [])
```

- Furthermore, if there are any other variables that should reflect changes in the UI, they can be convert to states as well.

Comment: I think this answer is probably a good guess of the problem OP is facing. However, shouldn't props change rerender also cause a re-render? (unless component is wrapped by `React.memo`) And when the `key` change - by remounting component? (just a remark related to your list of rerender triggers, unrelated to OP)

Comment: It's a common misconception. The thing it that whenever any of the parent components re-render, the prop values also change, which triggers the re-render in the child component. So while it's technically true, it's still ultimately a result of the parent comp's re-render.

Comment: Fair enough, so props changing, including `key` is indeed in scenario `2.`

Comment: Thank you so much, You are a legend, I have already tried to use 'useState' and 'useEffect;' before but with no luck that confirm that there is a huge different between a senior and a junior dev

Answer (score -1):

for that try using the `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`.

You are trying to make the text change after a specific interval in this case 1 second.

You should also consider doing that will CSS animations, it seems this is overkill.

```js
const change = () => { 
  titlep2 = projectsTitleKeyWords[index]
  index = ++index % projectsTitleKeyWords.length
  
  console.log(titlep2)
  setInterval(change, 1000)
}
change()
```

Comment: This will not work, as each time `change` is called, it will setup a new `setInterval` loop, each of them running `change` many times. `setTimeout` is fine for this, or, in order to use `setInterval` it needs to be called once outside of `change`.